# Google Play Subscription: Detect if subscription is auto renewed in android

Tags: java, android, in-app-subscription

Is there a way to detect auto renewed subscription?
I have an android app with renewable yearly subscriptions. I would like to know if user plan has been auto renewed or not.

As I can see renewals in Google Console and also the Receipt received.
(orderId ends with  ..0, ..1)),
but when querying the method, the purchase response is same as before.
I am using this to get the purchased subscription details.
Kindly ignore logs!

```
Purchase.PurchasesResult result = billingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);
Log.e("BillingActivity: ", ""+result.getPurchasesList());
```

and,

```
billingClient.queryPurchaseHistoryAsync(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS, new PurchaseHistoryResponseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPurchaseHistoryResponse(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<PurchaseHistoryRecord> list) {
                        if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                            if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                                Log.e("BillingActivity: ", "" + list);
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity_Sub.this, "History is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Any help on this?
I just need to know if the plan is auto renewed.

Data in Logs:

> E/ASA:: [PurchaseHistoryRecord. Json: {"productId":"my_dummy_plan","purchaseToken":"blgdbeodmiajcbemdmdepjfe.AO-J1OyPfc8gwQrW_k-8TS7DsNge9zVjNqd21MajO0--0duhduhduhduh-igWOd0EypH6ppMtF4ZQHV0y0CYVeduhduhduh","purchaseTime":1635328168793,"developerPayload":null}]

Answer (score 1):

Note: Subscription renewals do not need to be acknowledged.

If a subscription renews succesfully, the subscription continues to be returned by **BillingClient.queryPurchasesAsync()**

A **SUBSCRIPTION_RENEWED** notification is also sent when a subscription renews. Your app should make sure the user is still entitled to the subscription and then update the subscription state with the new expiryTimeMillis provided in the subscription resource returned from the Google Play Developer API. The subscription resource looks similar to the following:

```
{
  "kind": "androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase",
  ...
  "expiryTimeMillis": updated_expiration_time,
  "autoRenewing": true,
  ...
  "paymentState": 1  # Payment received
}
```

Note: If a subscription is set to renew on the 29th, 30th, or 31st of the month, in the next February of a non-leap year, the subscription renewal day is moved to the 28th and continues to renew on the 28th of each month for the duration of the subscription. Similarly, if a user starts a subscription on March 31st, the subscription renews on April 30th and continues to renew on the 30th of each month.

Comment: queryPurchasesAsync is not a method of V3 billing library, I need a solution for V3
:(

Comment: Hello Snorlax, I tried with the same.. Still getting the old subscription response.